# Why does Coq not allow constructor argument types to be strictly positive mutual inductive types?

Tags: coq, inductive-type, positivity

*Note: Apologies for the wicked mouthful of a title. I'm still getting acquainted with Coq terminology, so I might not have chosen the best words. If you have a better title suggestion, edits are more than welcome!*

Page 122 of the [Coq reference manual](https://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs430/coq/pdf/Reference-Manual.pdf) describes the strict positivity criteria:

> The constant X occurs strictly positively in T in the following cases:
>
> - X does not occur in T
> - T converts to (X t1 . . . tn) and X does not occur in any of ti
> - T converts to ∀ x : U, V and X does not occur in type U but occurs strictly positively in type V
> - T converts to (I a1 . . . am t1 . . . tp) where I is the name of an inductive declaration of the
>   form Ind(Γ)[m](I : A := c1 : ∀p1 : P1, . . . ∀pm : Pm, C1; . . . ; cn : ∀p1 : P1, . . . ∀pm : Pm, Cn )
>   (in particular, it is **not mutually defined** and it has m parameters) and X does not occur in any
>   of the ti
>   , and the (instantiated) types of constructor Ci{pj/aj}j=1...m of I satisfy the nested positivity condition for X

The emphasis (i.e., around "not mutually defined") was added by me.

Why is `I` required to not be mutually defined? If we removed this restriction (i.e., we allowed `I` to be mutually defined), would this introduce inconsistency into the system? If so, I'd greatly appreciate an example (e.g., where you prove `False`).

Comment: Mutually defined inductive types can be encoded as a single inductive type (provided they live in the same sort), so I don't think the restriction is foundational. If I had to guess, I'd bet that this has to do with implementation hassle.